# how to send email with a file attached in android

Tags: email, android-intent, email-attachments

i have created file myown.txt, viewed it from file explorer.path is data->data->com.contacts->files->myown.txt.i wanted to send that file containing contact details as a attachment to my email id
my code is like this:

btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
                btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    sendEmail();
                }


            public void sendEmail(){
                String strfile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/sdcard/myown.txt";
                File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageState(),strfile);

                 EditText textTo =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextTo);
                 EditText textSubject =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextSubject);
                 TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                 if(!textTo.getText().toString().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                  final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                  emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
                  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{ textTo.getText().toString()});
                  emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, textSubject.getText());
                  //emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, tv.getText());
                 emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.fromFile(f));
                  ContactsbackupActivity .this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter an email address..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

        }
            });




working on android 2.2. i can only get the textview in email  but not the file. so please do let me know how to solve this problem.thanking you
```

Answer (score 0):

hey it worked i dont know how.i developed the program in one system and i was executing on other one.There are some variation in  configuration thats why it shows error.thanx a lot.hv a great day